# Why real device barometer sensor doesn't connect to an app?

Tags: java, android, sensors

I am trying to make a simple Android app that gets data from barometer and simply prints it on textview. When I launch my app on a real device (my Android), the text doesn't change. I heard that I need some permissions. I made a research on internet, but didn't find anything.

This is my code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView txt;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor pressureSensor;
    private boolean hasBarometer;
    private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            float[] values = sensorEvent.values;
            txt.setText(String.format("%.3f mbars",values[0]));
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt = findViewById(R.id.txt);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        pressureSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener,pressureSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Primitive sensors usually don't need permission to access them. But pressure sensors are not very common, make sure the used device really has one. Also check logcat for errors while app is running.